# Enabling font weight and colour in RESULTS block of org-babel

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Is there any way to enable font weight and colours in the `#+RESULTS` block of `org-babel`?

For example, calling `ls` with the `--color` option renders font weights and colours as expected in the shell, but not when rendered within the `#+RESULTS` block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
ls --color ~/
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Applications      |
| Desktop           |
| Documents         |
| Downloads         |
| Library           |
...
```

[Screenshot of `ls` with and without `--color` in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6iBx.png)

Another example is the `node` module `chalk`, which appears in the `#+RESULTS` block as plaintext:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC js
const chalk = require('chalk');

console.log(chalk.red('Hello world!'));
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Hello world!
: undefined
```

[Screenshot of `chalk` in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXApJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with. Use it as an interactive function by running it while your cursor is on the code block (not the results block). You will need to have the `xterm-color` package installed.

```
(defun org-babel-color-results()
  "Color org babel results.
Use the :wrap header argument on your code block for best results.
Without it, org may color overtop with whatever default coloring it
uses for literal examples.
Depends on the xterm-color package."
  (interactive)
  (when-let ((result-start (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result nil nil)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char result-start)
      (when (looking-at org-babel-result-regexp)
        (let ((element (org-element-at-point)))
          (pcase (org-element-type element)
            (`fixed-width
             (let ((post-affiliated (org-element-property :post-affiliated element))
                   (end (org-element-property :end element))
                   (contents (org-element-property :value element))
                   (post-blank (org-element-property :post-blank element)))
               (goto-char post-affiliated)
               (delete-region post-affiliated end)
               (insert (xterm-color-filter contents))
               (org-babel-examplify-region post-affiliated (point))
               (insert (make-string post-blank ?\n ))
               ))
            ((or `center-block `quote-block `verse-block `special-block)
             (let ((contents-begin (org-element-property :contents-begin element))
                   (contents-end (org-element-property :contents-end element)))
               (goto-char contents-begin)
               (let ((contents (buffer-substring contents-begin contents-end)))
                 (delete-region contents-begin contents-end)
                 (insert (xterm-color-filter contents)))))))))))
```

Or add a hook

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-babel-color-results)
```

[This link](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color/issues/40) was my inspiration.

One thing I haven't figured out is that although it colors the text when your not using the `:wrap` argument on your code block, the coloring for [Org Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) `:`  seems to override it. You can see the color is applied however by simply deleting the `:`  for a line expected to have color.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, using org-mode version 9.4.4 it was necessary to specify `:wrap results` and `:results verbatim` or the text was rendered plain.